# Regex to parse out a part of URL

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

I am having the following data,

```
data
http://hsotname.com/2016/08/a-b-n-r-y-u
https://www.hostname.com/best-food-for-humans
http://www.hostname.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/a-w-w-2.jpg
http://www.hostname.com/a/geniusbar/
http://www.hsotname.com/m/
http://www.hsotname.com/
```

I want to avoid the first http:// or https:// and check for the last '/' and parse out the remaining parts of the URL. But the challenge here is, we have '/' on the end of few URLs as well. The output which I want is,

```
parsed
a-b-n-r-y-u
best-food-for-humans
a-w-w-2.jpg
NULL
NULL 
NULL
```

Can anybody help me to find the last / and parse out the remaining part of the URL? I am new to regex and any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `.*\/(.*)` should do the trick

Comment: I'm confused why you think you need a regex? Splitting on the last `/` gets pretty close

Comment: or you could use `rindex('/')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to simply split on "/" and take the last element:

```
"http://hsotname.com/2016/08/a-b-n-r-y-u".split("/")[-1]
# 'a-b-n-r-y-u'

"http://www.hostname.com/a/geniusbar/".split("/")[-1]
# ''
```

Answer (score 1):

Regexes are probably not the way you should do this - considering that you marked the question `python`, try (assuming the URL is in name `url`):

```
last-part = url.split('/')[-1]
```

This splits the URL into a list of substrings between slashes, and stores the last one in `last-part`.

If you insist on using regexes, though, matching on the end of the string is helpful here. Try `/[^/]*$`, which matches a slash, followed by any number of non-slashes, followed by the end of the string.

If you were to want to match the last non-empty part following a slash (if you didn't want the last three examples to return `""`), you could do `/[^/]*/?$`, which allows but does not require a single slash at the very end.

Answer (score 1):

Check from the end of the URL, and match every thing but /

```
[^/]+?$
```

or

```
\b[^/]+?\b$
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with something like this:

```
\/([^/]*)$
```

It'll match the last slash, then grab anything after it (if anything) that isn't a slash.

Answer (score 0):

Regex isn't the best tool in this case. Just use str.rfind:

```
[url[url.rfind('/'):] for url in data]
```

Will give you what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

Possibly over kill for the example, but if you need to deal with location fragments/just location names (ie, the last forward slash is part of the http etc... (splitting `http://hostname.com` and taking the last `/` will give you `hostname.com` - `urlsplit` will give a path of `''` instead) then'll you're probably safer off using:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urlsplit
>>> urls = ['http://hsotname.com/2016/08/a-b-n-r-y-u', 'https://www.hostname.com/best-food-for-humans', 'http://www.hostname.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/a-w-w-2.jpg', 'http://www.hostname.com/a/geniusbar/', 'http://www.hsotname.com/m/', 'http://www.hsotname.com/']
>>> [urlsplit(url).path.rpartition('/')[2] for url in urls]
['a-b-n-r-y-u', 'best-food-for-humans', 'a-w-w-2.jpg', '', '', '']
```

Comment: But when you have a url like `hostname.com` you will get the full url again.. I guess it depends on what the OP wants at that point.

Comment: @double_j true, but you'd probably be able to do a couple of bits with the attempt that `urlsplit` has made to try and work that out, but yes - it would be down to the OP to work out what logic they wish to apply in edge cases...